# A POI related code block running dead slow

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have below piece of code block containing loops:

```
Row row = null;
Cell cell = null;
String dataVal = null;
String[] temp = null;

for (int j = 0; j < this.myDataValues.size(); j++) {
  row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
  temp = this.finalRowValues.get(j);

   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
       cell = row.createCell(i);

       dataVal = temp[i];

            if (NumberUtils.isNumber(dataVal)) {
                double d = Double.valueOf(dataVal);
                cell.setCellValue(d);
                cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
                cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("currency"));
            } else if (isValidDate(dataVal)) {
                cell.setCellValue(dataVal);
                cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
                cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("date"));
            } else {
                cell.setCellValue(temp[i]);
                cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("data"));
            }
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
        }
    }
```

Where `myDataValues` is a `List` of `String[]` with each `String[]` object containing 4 values.

I am running this in Rational Application Developer version 8 and Apache POI 3.8.

There are around 5500 elements in `myDataValues` which is a pretty small value I believe.

However, this code block is taking more then a hour to run.

I think there is something wrong with this. 5500 elements with each containing 4 elements should run pretty fast and should be a question of several minutes. What could be the possible cause? Is there a way to make this block run faster?

There is nothing wrong with available memory of the machine or any other such issues. Everything is working as expected and I have verified it. The issue is in this block only.

Comment: *I think there is something wrong with this* use a profiler to confirm your guesses. The profiler will give you a more accurate answer about where's the bottleneck. Also, tell us which version of Apache POI you're using, I know the latest version (3.9 nowadays) has improved the performance when working with Excel files.

Comment: You should break sheet.autoSizeColumn(i) out to its own loop at the very end.  As you have it, you've got it running in a nested loop.

Comment: @developerwjk: Not getting you! j loop is the outer loop (row loop) while i loop is the column loop... and I am running autosize on every column... is that wrong ?

Comment: as @developerwjk points the autosizing of columns should be a one time activity.right now for every cell write it gets resized.

Comment: @NikunjChauhan - To your comment earlier ... Think about it this way.when manually creating an excel sheet would you resize the column after writing into it or would you rather fill the sheet first and then resize ? either put it into a new for loop outside or add if(j == this.myDataValues.size()-1) {sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);}

Comment: @Chetya: Got the point! thanks! Just to get information, is autosize() column time consuming.. is it the reason for performance impact ?

Comment: I have to admit, that I haven't checked the code right now, but there are common problems with autosize and unavailable fonts, therefore I'm quite sure that autosize loops through each cell of the column, determines their font and render their values for the max. column width ... this is definitely something you want to do only once per column

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your processing is very slow because you're calling `autoSizeColumn` for every row.  From the [Javadocs for the `autoSizeColumn` method](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#autoSizeColumn(int)):

> This process can be relatively slow on large sheets, so this should
>   normally only be called once per column, at the end of your
>   processing.

Place the calls to `autoSizeColumn` outside of the loop that creates the rows, in its own `for` loop only on the columns.  This will minimize calls to this method and improve your performance.

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference...

In my case, I had 1 millions plus, and the AutoSizeColumn still slow (even in the end).

So, I considerely boost the performance, just storing the column index and content length of every values (in a Dictionary), when it is large than last stored.

In the end of all process, just "foreach" the list and set the width of the column with sheet.SetColumnWidth.

- With autosize: never end;
- With witdh: 3 seconds.

Pseudo-code

```
if(!dictionary.Any(a => a.Key == columnIndex))
                {
                    dictionary.Add(columnIndex, columnContent.Length);
                }
                else if(dictionary.Any(a => a.Key == columnIndex && a.Value < columnContent.Length))
                {
                    dictionary[columnIndex] = columnContent.Length;
                }
```

And in the end

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> column in dictionary)
        {
            sheet.SetColumnWidth(column.Key, column.Value*300);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
for (int j = 0; j < this.myDataValues.size(); j++) {
  row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
  temp = this.finalRowValues.get(j);

   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
       cell = row.createCell(i);

       dataVal = temp[i];

            if (NumberUtils.isNumber(dataVal)) {
                double d = Double.valueOf(dataVal);
                cell.setCellValue(d);
                cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
                cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("currency"));
            } else if (isValidDate(dataVal)) {
                cell.setCellValue(dataVal);
                cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
                cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("date"));
            } else {
                cell.setCellValue(temp[i]);
                cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("data"));
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
    }
```